# I accidentally cloned/pulled from github. How do I undo?

Tags: git, github

I tried to research this on stackoverflow first but couldn't find a solution.

I was trying to push to a branch but there was a conflict. So I think I think I somehow cloned the branch. The branch I cloned basically had no code on it and was really behind where I was with my current coding. So I essentially lost all of my progress.

How do I get back to where my project was before I did any github cloning/pulling? I didn't upload my original code anywhere else.

```
13fa3c6 (HEAD -> registration) HEAD@{0}: commit (merge): Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/registration' into registration
92b05f0 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD
92b05f0 HEAD@{2}: commit: Finished creating user registration functionality.
953ec91 HEAD@{3}: commit: Added validation to password, repeatpassword and email input fields on the registration form.
7624f4b HEAD@{4}: commit: Added validation to password, repeatpassword and email input fields on the registration form.
0c1743e HEAD@{5}: commit: Created the web form for the registration page. Also made the 'submit' button take the user to the login page.
b60df75 (dbtest) HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from dbtest to registration
7993f1a HEAD@{8}: reset: moving to HEAD
7993f1a HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from main to dbtest
13a838a (main) HEAD@{10}: clone: from https://github.com/xyz
```

that's all the data I have when I do git reflog

Comment: I'm sorry to say it but to the best of my knowledge you are sol.

Comment: If you committed your work, you should be fine. If you overwrote uncommitted changes in the working directory, you are SOL

Comment: how can it be gone? how is there no undo option for something like this?

Comment: You told git to overwrite your files.  Maybe you didn't realize that's what you were doing, but that's not git's fault.

Comment: My git branch didn't receive any commits for some reason. Also what does SOL mean?

Comment: Your reflog looks perfectly normal. You might also add the output from `git log --decorate --oneline --graph` (or at least the top 10 or 20 commits it prints). It looks like you merged the upstream of your branch into your branch; if that's the case, you can undo the merge with `git reset`—but *be careful* with `git reset` as that's also a command that can destroy work irrecoverably.

Comment: so i just type 'git reset' into the terminal ?

Comment: Okay I somehow fixed it. I accepted it was over and started to re-write. I then reopened pycharm, and my code was back to normal lol

Answer (score 0):

You just merged the remote branch into your local branch. You could simply `reset` your branch to the previous commit:

```
git reset <your-last-commit-on-local-branch>
```

You will be left with unstaged modifications (the commits that were merged into your local branch) that you will have to add/remove.

Comment: what do I put in the '<your-last-commit-on-local-branch>' section? Do I put 'HEAD@{2}' to go back to that commit?

Comment: You have to put the hash of the last commit you had in your local branch, sorry but I don't remember exactly how the reflog is built

Comment: I don't think this will help, because he never committed his most recent work.  There's nothing to go back to.

Comment: Since he was trying to push to the remote, I suppose he did

Comment: Yeah it doesn't change anything. I thought I was replacing the github work with my local work, not the other way around... There's no way of going back right?

Comment: could you share a log of your local and remote branch?

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: you can run `git log registration` and `git log origin/registration`